# Checking two conditions in R

Tags: r

I want to check for two conditions

```
if(((i-1)*80)<j<((i*(80-1)))
      print i
```

Comment: Use `&` between your two tests and have a look to `?Logic` and to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: eg `x <- 1:10; x > 3 & x < 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R's parser does not accept  a variable sandwiched between two inequalities. You need to form a logical conjunction:

```
if( (i-1)*80 < j & j < (i*(80-1) ) {  print( i ) }
```

But I fear that you think this will succeed without further programming support and that would only be true if R functioned as a macro processor that has an implicit loop such as you have with SAS or SPSS. R would need an explicit loop or a vectorized call for that to do anything interesting. You should explain the goals of this line of code sot that a more complete answer can be offered. I also fear that you actually need the `ifelse` function since R's version of `if` will only test a single logical value at one time whereas `ifelse` or R's logical operators themselves are designed for 'vectorized' situations.

Comment: data <- read.csv("bins.txt", header = FALSE)
for (j in data)
  {
    for (i in 1:20)
    {
      m=(i-1)*80
      n=(i*80)-1
      if(m<j & j<n)
        {
          print (i)

        }  
    }
  }

Comment: This statement worked for me:  my_vector[length(my_vector)+1] = i